# Valid route naming for nongranted accounts

Tags: spring, rest, http, spring-mvc, routes

I have a REST controller and i need to write a valid routing name. For example i have Roles and Accounts entities, and if i want to get accounts of a particular role (accounts that have this role) i use this route:

```
/roles/{roleId}/accounts
```

Where {roleId} is the id of role. 
I need to write a route for method, that get a list of account of role that is not assigned to them. For example i need to load a list of users that not have this role. The one idea that i have is to write this route:

```
/roles/{roleId}/accounts/notgranted
```

Can someone help me?)

Comment: Cant you do this on query level?

Comment: @Alien i need only valid naming) Accordingly to REST routing names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rest` api use `URIs` to address resources. What it does matter is that every resource should be uniquely addressable.
So

```
/roles/{roleId}/accounts/notgranted
/roles/{roleId}/accounts/granted
```

are valid URI.